# Show $\sigma^{-1} (i j)\sigma = ((i)\sigma (j)\sigma)$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

> Let $n \geq 2$ be an integer and $i, j \in \{1, 2, ..., n\} $ be distinct elements. Let $\sigma \in S_n$, Show that $\sigma^{-1} (i j)\sigma = ((i)\sigma (j)\sigma)$

---

let  $\tau=\sigma^{-1}(ij)\sigma$, then $((i)\sigma) \tau=((i)\sigma)\sigma^{-1} (i j)\sigma=i(ij)\sigma=e(j)\sigma=(j)\sigma$, similarly, we we can get $((j)\sigma)\tau=(i)\sigma$.

Let $k\in \{1,2,3\dots,n\}$ and $k\neq (i)\sigma\neq (j)\sigma$, then $(k)\tau =k$

---

I am still don't what I need to show to complete the proof, can anyone give me hit? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you mean $(\sigma(i)\sigma(j))$, or someone convinced to use quite nonstandard notation.

Comment: You need to show that the two are equal, as functions. The function on the right sends $(i)\sigma \mapsto (j)\sigma$ and $(j)\sigma \mapsto (i)\sigma$, while it fixes all $k$ distinct from $(i)\sigma$ and $(j)\sigma$. Can you show the function on the left does the exact same thing?

Comment: What if $ij\equiv 0\pmod n$?

Answer (score 0):

$$((i)\sigma)\sigma^{-1}(ij)\sigma=(i)(ij)\sigma=(j)\sigma$$
and
$$((j)\sigma)\sigma^{-1}(ij)\sigma=(j)(ij)\sigma=(j)\sigma$$

So, $(i)\sigma\mapsto(j)\sigma$ and $(j)\sigma\mapsto(i)\sigma$.